# How can I change a string's letters while trying to disguise a password?

Tags: python, passwords

I'm trying to create a simple username and password script in Python 3.5.1, and I cannot figure out how to make the user input a password, and then for it to be covered up with an asterisk so it cannot be read.

This is my code so far:

```
import time
print ("Hello!")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Welcome to the Username and Password python test!")
time.sleep(3)
Username = input ("Please enter your desired Username ")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Your username is "+ Username)
time.sleep(1)
Q1 = input ("Is this correct? 'Y' or 'N' ")
if Q1 == "N":
    Q2 = input ("Would you like to change it? ")
    if Q2 == "Y": Username = input ("Please re enter your Username ")
    print ("Your Username is now "+ Username)
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("You cannot change your Username now")
    time.sleep(2)
if Q1 == "Y": time.sleep(1)
Password = input ("Please input your Password ")
time.sleep(3)
Q3 = input ("Please enter your Username ")
if Q3 == Username:
    time.sleep(1)
    Q4 = input ("Please now input your Password ")
    time.sleep(1)
    if Q4 == Password:
        print ("Correct")
        time.sleep(2)
        print ("Thank you for using the Username and Password python test")
    else:
        print ("Incorrect Password")
else:
    print ("Username not found")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit question and explain what happens with that code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) module for this. `getpass.getpass()` allows the user to enter input without echoing (printing to the terminal).

You may also want to look at [`getpass.user()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getuser) for some of your program's functionality.